# How to print a functional component inside loop - react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to print my functional component inside a loop. 
but I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected
```

my code:

```
render(){
 ...

return (

...


    { this.state.coupons.length > 0 ? (

                                    Object.keys(reducedData).map(obj => {

                                              var row = {} ;
                                              row.title = '';
                                              row.coupon_code = '';
                                                reducedData[obj].map(item =>
                                                    {
                                                      row.title = item.title;
                                                      row.coupon_code += item.coupon_code;
                                                    }

                                                     {<MyShadyabsRow  row={row}/>}


                                              )
                                        })

                                  ) : (
                                    <tr></tr>
                                  )

                                  }

...

)

}
```

my error line is at this line:

```
{<MyShadyabsRow  row={row}/>}
```

my functional component:

```
import React from ‘react’;

const MyShadyabsRow = ({row}) => (
  <tr>
      <td>
          <a href="#">
              <i className="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true">
                  <span>پرینت</span>
              </i>
          </a>
      </td>
      <td>{row.title}</td>
      <td>۱۳۹۶/۱۰/۱۰</td>
      <td>{row.coupon_code}</td>
  </tr>
);

export default MyShadyabsRow;
```

Comment: You must return your component from map function in order to render

Comment: return <MyShadyabsRow  row={row}/>

But since you have 2 map functions. best solution is to make a variable to be able to return it from outer map function.

Comment: What I'm not sure about, is whether you need to render `<MyShadyabsRow  row={row}/>` every time *in* `reducedData[obj].map` function or *after* the map function?

Comment: I want to render my component after `reducedData[obj].map(item =>
                                                {
                                                  row.title = item.title;
                                                  row.coupon_code += item.coupon_code;
                                                }` .

Answer (score 0):

actually what are missing is the return statement inside the render and also the different closures of the functions are not correct, for example:

```
                                            reducedData[obj].map(item =>
                                                {
                                                  row.title = item.title;
                                                  row.coupon_code += item.coupon_code;
                                                }

                                                 {<MyShadyabsRow  row={row}/>}
                                          )
```

as you may see, you are closing the `(item => {....} ) which is  not corret.

```
this.state.coupons.length > 0 ? (
        Object.keys(reducedData).map(obj => {
            let row = {};
            row.title = '';
            row.coupon_code = '';
            reducedData[obj].map(item => {
                row.title = item.title;
                row.coupon_code += item.coupon_code;
            })
            //this will return the object after the map is applied.
            //the error was on the closure of your code and the use of {} wrapping your component.
            return (<MyShadyabsRow  row = { row } />)
        })): (
            <tr></tr>
        )
```

Comment: It doesn't work and I got this erro: `Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected , (106:49)
[0] 
[0]   104 |                                                 }
[0]   105 | 
[0] > 106 |                                                  return <MyShadyabsRow  row={row}/>
[0]       |                                                  ^
[0]   107 | 
[0]   108 | 
[0]   109 |                                           )`

Comment: sorry @S.M_Emamian I put the return outside the map, it is inside :) check it out now.

Comment: I don't want to use `MyShadyabsRow` component inside map.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian sorry, I noticed my mistake, I thought you wanted to return an array inside of you array, instead you want to return the sum of objects inside your 2nd array.
I edited my answer to fit this approach. take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The line in question is indeed wrong. You need to return the component, and right now you're just wrapping it in curly brackets, which makes no sense in that context.

That faulty line should instead be

```
return <MyShadyabsRow  row={row}/>;
```

I'm assuming you want to render one `MyShadyabsRow` component for each key in `reducedData`.

Answer (score 0):

Map function will return multiple components and since you have outer object key it will iterate again. So from map function you cannot render JSX component you map compenent to each element of array. that is why bracket syntax is not valid.

```
{ this.state.coupons.length > 0 ? (
   Object.keys(reducedData).map(obj => {
       var row = {} ;
       row.title = '';
       row.coupon_code = '';
       return reducedData[obj].map(item =>
                                   {
                                      row.title = item.title;
                                      row.coupon_code += item.coupon_code;
                                      return (<MyShadyabsRow  row={row}/>)
                                    }





                                   )
        })
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `{<MyShadyabsRow  row={row}/>}` is inside the map function

```
reducedData[obj].map(item =>{
      row.title = item.title;
      row.coupon_code += item.coupon_code;
      return (<MyShadyabsRow  row={row}/>);
)
```